# scikit-learn RandomizedSearchCV doesn't utilise all available cores

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I'm using RandomizedSearchCV to optimize and evaluate several ML models. I'm trying to run the optimization process using joblib `Parallel()`. But, when running my code on an HPC using 16 cores, only two of them are used.

```
    jobs = 16        
    x = Parallel(n_jobs=jobs, backend='multiprocessing', verbose=3)(delayed(fit)(m, 
                 X_train,
                 y_train,
                 n_iter= 3,
                 cv = 3,
                 return_train_score= True,
                 scoring='r2',
                 refit='r2',
                 n_jobs=4,
                 verbose = 3) for m in models)
```

*EDIT:* If `m` corresponds to 2 models tested, then `Parallel()` uses two cores and the other 14 cores are unused (0.0%). The iterations/folds of the `fit()` function seem to run as threads on these two cores.

**Question: Is there a way to nest the parallel execution, so that all cores are used?**

---

Full working example:

```
import sys
import os
import yaml
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, Matern
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import loguniform, uniform, truncnorm, randint

from joblib import parallel_backend, Parallel, delayed

rng = np.random.default_rng()

def gen_data(n, p, rng):
    prob = 0.5
    xm_a1 = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    xm_a2 = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    Xm = xm_a1 + xm_a2
    xf_a1 = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    xf_a2 = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    r_m = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    r_f = rng.binomial(1, prob, size=(n, p))
    xc_a1 = r_m * xm_a2 + (1 - r_m) * xm_a1
    xc_a2 = r_f * xf_a2 + (1 - r_f) * xf_a1
    Xc = xc_a1 + xc_a2
    return Xc

def predict_r2_score(x, X, y):
    y_pred = x.best_estimator_.predict(X)
    return r2_score(y_test,y_pred)

def fit(mod,X ,y , **kwargs):
    grid_search = RandomizedSearchCV(mod['estimator'], mod['param'], **kwargs)
    grid_search.fit(X, y)
    return grid_search, mod['model']

def generate_phenotype(X, n_features, n_samples, var_add, var_dom, var_epi, chunks = 512):
    
    sample = rng.choice(range(X.shape[1]), n_features, replace=False)
    X = X[0:n_samples,sample]
    
    MAF = (X.mean(axis=0)/2).reshape(1,n_features) #+ 1e-3
    
    elim = np.where(MAF == 0)[1]
    X = np.delete(X,elim,axis=0)
    elim = np.where(MAF == 1)[1]
    X = np.delete(X,elim,axis=0)
    
    print(X.shape)
    n_features = X.shape[1]
    MAF = (X.mean(axis=0)/2).reshape(1,n_features)

    e = 1 - (var_add + var_dom + var_epi)
    var_add = var_add/n_features
    var_dom = var_dom/n_features
    var_epi = var_epi/(n_features*(n_features-1)//2)
    
    uA = rng.normal(0, np.sqrt(var_add), n_features)
    uD = rng.normal(0, np.sqrt(var_dom), n_features)
    uAA = rng.normal(0, np.sqrt(var_epi), n_features*(n_features-1)//2)
    e = rng.normal(0, np.sqrt(e), n_samples)
    
    
    xD = np.where(X == 1, 2*MAF, X)
    xD = np.where(xD == 2, 4*MAF-2, xD)

    wA = (X - 2*MAF)/np.sqrt(2*MAF*(1-MAF))
    wD = (xD - 2*(MAF**2))/(2*MAF*(1-MAF))
    
    wAA = np.zeros((n_samples, ))
    start, end = 0, 0
    for i in range(n_features-1):
        end += n_features-i-1
        wAA = wAA + np.sum(wA[:,i].reshape(n_samples,1)*wA[:,i+1:n_features]*uAA[start:end],1)
        start = end

    Y = np.matmul(wA, uA) + np.matmul(wD, uD) + wAA
    
    return Y + e


if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_size = 0.2
    n_informative = 1000
    n_features = 10000
    n_samples = 50000
    heritability = 0.7
    var_dom = 0.1
    var_epi = 0.1
    var_add = heritability - var_epi - var_dom
    
    G = gen_data(n_samples,n_features,rng)
    
    y = generate_phenotype(G, n_informative, n_samples, var_add, var_dom, var_epi)

    models = [{"model":"LinearRegression","estimator": LinearRegression(), "param": [{}]},
              {"model":"GaussianProcessRegressor","estimator": GaussianProcessRegressor(), "param": [{'copy_X_train':[False],'n_restarts_optimizer': [10],"alpha":  loguniform(1e-5, 1e-2),"kernel": [RBF(l,length_scale_bounds=(1e-20, 100000.0)) for l in np.logspace(-10, 1, 10)]},{'copy_X_train':[False],'n_restarts_optimizer': [10],"alpha":  loguniform(1e-10, 1e-2),"kernel": [Matern(l,length_scale_bounds=(1e-20, 100000.0)) for l in np.logspace(-10, 1, 10)]}]},]

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(G, y.reshape(n_samples,1), test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle = True)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

    y_train = scaler.fit_transform(y_train.reshape(-1,1))
    y_test = scaler.transform(y_test.reshape(-1,1))

    y_train = y_train.ravel()
    y_test = y_test.ravel()

    jobs = 16
    
    print("Start model fitting ...")
            
    x = Parallel(n_jobs=jobs, backend='multiprocessing', verbose=3)(delayed(fit)(m, 
                 X_train,
                 y_train,
                 n_iter= 3,
                 cv = 3,
                 return_train_score= True,
                 scoring='r2',
                 refit='r2',
                 n_jobs=4,
                 verbose = 3) for m in models)
    print("Done model fitting")

    res = []
    for i in range (len(x)):
        m = models[i]['model']
        r = predict_r2_score(x[i][0],X_test,y_test)
        res.append([m,r,n_samples, n_features, n_informative, heritability, var_add, var_dom, var_epi])

    df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['models', 'r2','sample', 'features', 'informative', 'heritability','add', 'dom', 'epi'])

print(df)
```

Comment: Note that multiprocessing need very slow data transfer that may explain why this is slow. Otherwise, It might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841900 .

Comment: The problem is that I have 16 cores. All of them are spawned, but 14 of them show 0.0% usage. I would like to spread the calculation over all cores because each model gets trained 9 times (3 iterations over 3 folds). Each of the training instances is basically a separate run and should run on one core. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It seems like you already know the issue is that you parallelize over `for m in models`, and there are only two entries there. You can do the whole search on a single `RandomizedSearchCV` if that's acceptable?